# Apcahe NIFI -- Unable to configure ConsumeKafkaRecord

Tags: apache-nifi

I have set JsonPathReader as a RecordReader . But in Controller Service tab JsonPathReader is showing invalid "'JSON PATHS ' is invalid because no JSON Paths were specified". and schema access Strategy is'Infer schema'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to infer schema and want all the fields for each record, then you should use the JsonTreeReader.

The JsonPathReader should be able to infer schema as well, but it still requires you to specify one or more json paths to extract. The scenario would be that your json has many fields, but you only know a couple of them and only want to extract the ones you know, so you can specify the json path to those fields.